# Powershell equivalent of C# List with Coordinates

Tags: c#, arrays, list, powershell

I'm trying to translate some C# code to Powershell code.

The problem I am having is trying to make an array in Powershell that will be in the same form as this array in C#:

```c#
List<Coordinate> coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
    coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(0, 0));
    coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(500, 100));
    coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(200, 400));
```

My best attempt in Powershell is this:

```c#
$Coordinates = @((0,0),(500,100),(200,400))
```

But when I use $Coordinates, it doesn't work with the API I'm feeding it to like the C# coordinates works with the same API. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate the code directly - with the caveat that you need to use the fully qualified type name for the constructors:

```
$coordinates = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Namespace.Coordinate]'
$coordinates.Add($(New-Object Namespace.Coordinate 0,0))
$coordinates.Add($(New-Object Namespace.Coordinate 500,100))
$coordinates.Add($(New-Object Namespace.Coordinate 200,400))
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me. Powershell spat some red text at me:
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Collections.Generic.List[Namespace.Coordinate]]: verify that the assembly containing this type
is loaded.

Comment: Replace `Namespace.Coordinate` with the actual type name of the `Coordinate` class